# Magento 2.3 How to configure Multiple website with different domain

Tags: magento2.3, multistore, multi-website, multidomain

i have magento 2.3 store and i want to two website setup with in 1 magento admin

> my website url like: www.xyz.com 
>  and another one is www.abc.com

but here i need also in both website different theme use so here i have confusion so i need another directory for another website ya in one directory i will do this  and which condition i will add in `index.php` or `htacess` file

any one help me anyone in this case

Advance Thanks!!

Comment: you can assign theme on website level, no need of another directory

Comment: @Pawan thank you for replay but how can do this can you explain in brief because if i will change url website wise then theme allocate then next step is what ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 support theme multi website feature then you do not have need to another directory.

You can setup multiple website using this reference : [Setup multiple website.](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-websites-magento-2.html)

And you can apply and configure theme using this reference : [Apply and configure storefront theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html)

I hope it helps!